# Go 1.18 Generics how to define a new-able type parameter with interface

Tags: go, generics

[This](https://go.dev/play/p/QFG96PVCJIi?v=gotip) used to work in go1.18beta1, but not works in go1.18rc1

```golang
package main

type A struct{}

func (*A) Hello() {
    println("Hello")
}

func Create[M any, PT interface {
    Hello()
    *M
}](n int) (out []*M) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        v := PT(new(M))
        v.Hello()
        out = append(out, v)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    println(Create[A](2))
}
```

Execute will throw

```
./prog.go:16:21: cannot use v (variable of type PT constrained by interface{Hello(); *M}) as type *M in argument to append:
    PT does not implement *M (type *M is pointer to interface, not interface)
```

Seems due to this limitation:

> Embedding a type parameter, or a pointer to a type parameter, as an unnamed field in a struct type is not permitted. Similarly, embedding a type parameter in an interface type is not permitted. Whether these will ever be permitted is unclear at present.

How can I do this in go1.18rc1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert `v` back to `*M` again.

```
out = append(out, (*M)(v))
```

The error you got is about assignability. In fact the quote in your question doesn't forbid embedding *a pointer type in an interface* . Both `M` and `PT` are different named type parameters and you can't assign one to the other without explicit conversion.

The conversion instead is valid because all types in `PT`’s type set (only `*M`) are convertible to `*M`.

Comment: Thanks, works now, but it works in beta1 before.

Comment: @wener I wouldn't assume anything from the implementations of earlier beta releases. There's a lot of stuff that got changed during the work-in-progress, that did compile with one beta and stopped compiling now. The only normative documentation we've got is the language specs with some amendments in the Go 1.18 release notes

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep watching the release note, mid march now, can't wait the release. Keep watching 1.19.