# Go with Generics: type *T is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter

Tags: go, generics

Probably a golang beginner's question :)

I'm facing following compiler error when trying to compile the code below.

I want to implement an object store for different types (here A and B) sharing a common ID field. Following the DRY idea, I want to implement the store using generics.

When adding an object, I want to set its ID field using the GS interface (the actual code is a bit more complex of course), but the compiler does not want me to do that.

> ./prog.go:29:7: item.SetId undefined (type *T is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)
>
> ./prog.go:34:24: A does not implement GS (SetId method has pointer receiver)

Is there a recommended way to solve this? Thanks in advance!!

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    ID      string
    AMember string
}
type B struct {
    ID      string
    BMember string
}

type GS interface {
    Id() string
    SetId(string)
}

func (s A) Id() string      { return s.ID }
func (s *A) SetId(i string) { s.ID = i }
func (s B) Id() string      { return s.ID }
func (s *B) SetId(i string) { s.ID = i }

type MyStore[T GS] struct {
    values map[string]*T
}

func (s *MyStore[T]) add(item *T) {
    item.SetId("aa")
    s.values["aa"] = item
}

func main() {
    var storeA = &MyStore[A]{}
    storeA.values = make(map[string]*A)
    a := &A{}

    storeA.add(a)

    fmt.Println(a.Id())
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### About using *T

In short, a type parameter **is not** its constraint. The constraint only determines what operations are available on `T`, it doesn't imply anything about `*T`, which is now just an unnamed pointer type. This is the meaning of:

> type *T is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter

As a consequence, as in your case, the method set of `*T` does not automatically include pointer receiver methods declared on the `T`'s concrete type `A`, and it does not implement interfaces that would be implemented by `*A`.

You'd have to make that explicit to the compiler by setting additional constraints. In a simplified form it would be something like:

```
func Foo[T any, PT interface { SetId(string); *T}](v T) {}
```

You can find more extensive examples and variations on this use case here:

- [Go 1.18 Generics how to define a new-able type parameter with interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440697/go-1-18-generics-how-to-define-a-new-able-type-parameter-with-interface)
- [How can I instantiate a new pointer of type argument with generic Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573113/how-can-i-instantiate-a-new-pointer-of-type-argument-with-generic-go/69575720#69575720)
- [What is the generic type for a pointer that implements an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090387/what-is-the-generic-type-for-a-pointer-that-implements-an-interface/72091526#72091526)

#### About implementing constraints

The reason this instantiation `&MyStore[A]{}` fails is clearly reported by the error message:

> A does not implement GS (SetId method has pointer receiver)

In other words `SetId()` is declared on `*A`, and not `A`. Therefore you should instantiate `MyStore` with `*A`:

```
var storeA = &MyStore[*A]{}
```

Then change the occurrences of `*T` in the struct/method definition to `T`:

```
type MyStore[T GS] struct {
    values map[string]T // just T instead of *T
}

func (s *MyStore[T]) add(item T) {
}
```

Upon instantiation with `*A` the type of the field would become equivalent to `map[string]*A` thus making the assignment `storeA.values = make(map[string]*A)` valid, and the method signature to `add(item *A)` thus allowing `storeA.add(&A{})`.

Fixed playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/dcUVJ5YQK_b

Comment: Nice! Besides, I think changing it to `(*item).SetId("aa")` could also solve the first issue.

Comment: @davidhcefx, that is a workaround, not a solution. You're converting *T to T, which brings its own set of problems. The main one is "what if *T is nil"?

Comment: @Alechan I'm not **converting** *T to T, it's a dereference. But you're right in that `nil` has to be checked before access.