# What is the generic type for a pointer that implements an interface?

Tags: go, pointers, generics

I have an interface like this

```
type A interface {
  SomeMethod()
}
```

I have an implementation of this interface via a struct pointer:

```
type Aimpl struct {}

func (a *Aimpl) SomeMethod() {}
```

I have a generic function that takes in a function with an A parameter like so:

```
func Handler[T A](callback func(result T)) {
  // Essentially what I'd like to do is result := &Aimpl{} (or whatever T is)
  callback(result)
}
```

Also I should add that I cannot modify the definition of `A` (it's coming from a library). I've tried this:

```
type MyA[T any] interface{
  A
  *T
}
```

But this code gives me an error:

```
func Handler[P any, T MyA[P]](callback func(result A)) {
    result := new(P)
    callback(result) // result does not implement interface. It's a pointer to a type, not a type
}
```

Example here: https://go.dev/play/p/NVo4plR1R-O

Comment: Generally you shouldn't care _what_ implements the interface, only that it _does_ implement it. You use the interface because you want to call its methods, and if it implements it, you can call the methods regardless of the receiver type.

Comment: @icza I agree with you in regards to a single interface, but this problem can be thought of as requiring a type that is the union of two interfaces. One that has `SomeMethod` and the other that can be `new`'d.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare the interface with a type parameter to make it require that the type implementing it is a pointer to its type parameter.

```golang
type A[P any] interface {
    SomeMethod()
    *P
}
```

With that you'll also need to modifier the handler's signature a bit.

```golang
func Handler[P any, T A[P]](callback func(result T)) {
    result := new(P)
    callback(result)
}
```

```golang
Handler(func(a *Aimpl) { fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a) })
```

https://go.dev/play/p/PY5iE7WoHt3

---

If you can't modify the definition of `A` then, as you've already found out, you can wrap it into your own.

```golang
type MyA[P any] interface {
    A
    *P
}
```

```golang
func Handler[P any, T MyA[P]](callback func(result T)) {
    result := new(P)
    callback(result)
}
```

```golang
Handler(func(a *Aimpl) { fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a) })
```

https://go.dev/play/p/50uzqCShnKb

Comment: Is there a way to make this work if I don't have control over the definition of `A`? (see edits to the question for a specific example)

Comment: @Max It works wtih `MyA` too, but you have to write the param as `result T` and not as `result A`: https://go.dev/play/p/i-fxUDDYBHi

Comment: Thanks. My real code was slightly different and I was invoking another library method that specifically required an `A`. The fix for this was to change `result := new(P)` to `var result A = new(P)`

Comment: This makes me think what kind usage this is/a terminology? there are definitely type conversion involved. But embedding a type pointer  to an interface and then convert such type to this interface type

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you write the constraints as `P any, T MyA[P]` there is no information that `P` implements a certain interface. In fact `P` is literally *anything* since you constrained it with `any`. The fact that `T` is then instantiated with `P` and produces a valid implementor, is unrelated to `P` itself. For the compiler there is no indication that `*P` (a pointer to any type) implements `A`.

If you want to make this work while keeping `A` in the callback signature, use a conversion. You still need to capture the base type in order to pass a non-nil pointer implementor, so your approach to wrap the interface together with a pointer constraint `*T` is correct in principle.

Hereafter using an unnamed constraint interface. Names of the type params are also inverted — `T` is the base type and `P` is the pointer type (logically...):

```
func (a *Aimpl) SomeMethod() { fmt.Printf("called, %T, %t\n", a, a == nil) }

func Handler[P interface { *T; A }, T any](callback func(A)) {
    p := P(new(T))
    callback(p)   
}
```

Then you need to instantiate `Handler` explicitly with `*Aimpl`:

```
func main() {
    Handler[*Aimpl](func(result A) { result.SomeMethod() }) 
    // prints: called, *main.Aimpl, false
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/96_UFVnfyO-

The other option to change the type of the callback allows you to use type inference instead of explicit instantiation, because then you already know the implementor. But at this point it's unclear how `A` fits in the picture:

```
func main() {
    // using the concrete type instead of A
    Handler(func(result *Aimpl) { result.SomeMethod() })
}
```