# Go - Enforce that an interface is only satisfied by types with a pointer receiver on a method?

Tags: go, generics

I'm doing some experimentation with type parameters to come up with a generic way of wiring up structs that generate a response to JSON HTTP requests.

The `Method` interface which the structs must implement has a `SetParams` method. This will work as expected as long as the implementation uses a pointer receiver.

My question: Is there any way of making this a compile time error if `SetParams` has a value receiver?

Here is an example demonstrating the problem with a `SetParams` that has a value receiver:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type PingParams struct {
    Name string
}

type PingResponse struct {
    Message string
}

func (p PingParams) Greeting() string {
    if p.Name != "" {
        return fmt.Sprintf("Hello, %s", p.Name)
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello, nobody!")
}

type GoodPing struct {
    Params PingParams
}

// SetParams has a pointer receiver.
func (m *GoodPing) SetParams(p PingParams) {
    fmt.Printf("assign %v with pointer receiver, Good!\n", p)
    m.Params = p
}
func (m GoodPing) Run() (*PingResponse, error) {
    return &PingResponse{Message: fmt.Sprintf("%T %s", m, m.Params.Greeting())}, nil
}

type BadPing struct {
    Params PingParams
}

// SetParams has a value receiver.
func (m BadPing) SetParams(p PingParams) {
    fmt.Printf("assign %v with value receiver, Bad!\n", p)
    m.Params = p
}
func (m BadPing) Run() (*PingResponse, error) {
    return &PingResponse{Message: fmt.Sprintf("%T %s", m, m.Params.Greeting())}, nil
}

type Method[M, RQ, RS any] interface {
    // Run builds the RPC result.
    Run() (*RS, error)
    // SetParams is intended to set the request parameters in the struct implementing the RPC method.
    // This then allows the request parameters to be easily available to all methods of the Method struct.
    // The method MUST have a pointer receiver. This is NOT enforced at compile time.
    SetParams(p RQ)
    // The following line requires the implementing type is a pointer to M.
    *M
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/72090807
}

func HandlerMethod[M, RQ, RS any, T Method[M, RQ, RS]](in json.RawMessage) (*RS, error) {
    // A real implementation of this would return a func for wiring into a request router

    var req RQ

    err := json.Unmarshal(in, &req)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var m T = new(M)

    m.SetParams(req)

    return m.Run()
}

func main() {

    payload := []byte(`{"Name": "Mark"}`)

    bad, err := HandlerMethod[BadPing, PingParams, PingResponse](payload)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(bad.Message)

    good, err := HandlerMethod[GoodPing, PingParams, PingResponse](payload)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(good.Message)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Eii8ADkmDxE

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: No, if a type has a method, it has that method. The interface cannot tell if the method is implemented incorrectly, and the incorrect receiver type is only one of inumerable ways to implement something incorrectly. A value receiver could work just as well in many cases if it contains the necessary internal pointers.

Comment: Also note that static analysis can detect `ineffective assignment to field BadPing.Params` in this case.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. Good catch on the static analysis. I had not seen it as VSCode was configured to run golang-ci-lint with --fast. statticcheck is now showing the ineffective assignment you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.

When in your code you do this:

```
var m T = new(M)
```

even if `T`'s type set includes only `*M` as a type term, `*M`'s method set includes methods declared on `M`. The compiler can't check for you **how** the method ends up in `*M`'s method set.

It is your responsibility when declaring the method `SetParam` on `BadPing` to make sure that the method doesn't attempt to unfruitfully modify the receiver.