# Using an interface pointer as a generic argument

Tags: go, generics

I have a generic `Storage` interface that I am using to manage and allocate memory.

```golang
type Storage[T any] interface {
    Allocate(size int)
}

type Base[T any] struct {
    data []T
}

func (b *Base[T]) Allocate(size int) {
    b.data = make([]T, size)
}
```

I am trying to then use this to constrain the generic argument of another struct.

```golang
type Tensor[T any, U Storage[T]] struct {
    data U
}

func NewTensor[T any, U Storage[T]](size int) *Tensor[T, U] {
    result := &Tensor[T, U]{}
    result.data = *new(U)
    result.data.Allocate(size)
    return result
}

func main() {
    t := NewTensor[float32, *Base[float32]](10)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x47de63]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.(*Base[...]).Allocate(...)
        .../goten/debug/debug.go:14
main.NewTensor[...](0x60)
        .../goten/debug/debug.go:24 +0x47
main.main()
        .../goten/debug/debug.go:29 +0x25
exit status 2
```

I am able to get something similar to work if I remove all of `Storage`'s pointer receivers and instead make them value receivers, but I need the reference in most cases.

Comment: Awkward but doable: https://go.dev/play/p/Zwx5RBzKNBE

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090387/what-is-the-generic-type-for-a-pointer-that-implements-an-interface/72090807#72090807