# Is there a way to constraint (generic) type parameters?

Tags: go, generics, protocol-buffers

I've just started to learn about generics. So I'm trying to generalize a driver for my custom database operating on some protobuf messages.

I want to find a way to further constraint my generic type but as a pointer, i.e. make sure (tell the compiler) that constraint E implements another method.

First, I've constrained what entities db can handle.

```
type Entity interface {
   pb.MsgA | pb.MsgB | pb.MsgC
}
```

Then, wrote a generic interface describing db capabilities so it can be used by different services handling respective proto messages:

```
type DB[E Entity] interface {
   Get(...) (E, error)
   List(...) ([]E, error)
   ...
}
```

So far so good. However, I also want these entities to be (de)serialized to be sent on wire, cloned and merged when communicating with the database. Something like this:

```
func Encode[E Entity](v *E) ([]byte, error) {
   return proto.Marshal(v)
}
```

However, the code above gives me the following error:

```
cannot use val (variable of type *E) as type protoreflect.ProtoMessage in argument to proto.Marshal: *E does not implement protoreflect.ProtoMessage (type *E is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)
```

The problem is `proto.Marshal` requires entity (*E) to implement `proto.Message` interface, namely `ProtoReflect()` method, which all my Entity types do implement, but it is not constrained and compiler cannot infer.

I have also tried to define entity as:

```
type Entity interface {
   *pb.MsgA | *pb.MsgB | *pb.MsgC
   proto.Message
}
```

However, that doesn't feel right in addition to I need to do some extra protreflect operations to instantiate my proto.Messages which Entity pointer reference to.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71444847/go-with-generics-type-t-is-pointer-to-type-parameter-not-type-parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```golang
func Encode[M interface { *E; proto.Message }, E Entity](v M) ([]byte, error) {
    return proto.Marshal(v)
}
```

If you'd like a more cleaner syntax than the above, you can delcare the message constraint:

```golang
type Message[E Entity] interface {
    *E
    proto.Message
}

func Encode[M Message[E], E Entity](v M) ([]byte, error) {
    return proto.Marshal(v)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/AYmSKYCfZ1_l

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! However, how can I call `Encode` function from inside another type parameterized function?

Comment: MichaelB. I'm not familiar enough with generics to know whether or not what you're trying is possible. You could do it with a simple type assertion but then you wouldn't need Encode, calling proto.Marshal directly would be enough. Keep an eye out for @blackgreen, if you see him around or in the chat ask him, he knows generics more than most here.

Comment: @MichaelB. if you're interested, here's a chat transcript regarding your question: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55853705#55853705

Comment: thanks again. Yes, this is exactly what I ended up with (after your intial post), i.e. `DB[M Message[E], E Entity]`, in order to get access to `proto.Message` related functions like `Encode`.

Comment: to answer you question about why not just constraint on `proto.Message`. Main reason was I wanted DB (it's local cache to be exact) to operate on objects instead of addresses to objects, which `proto.Message` really is. That way I could eliminate lots of headache when instantiating new objects of generic type without using protoreflection everywhere. The final solution is more elegant and clean, aside from ugly type parameters signature which needs everywhere now: `M Message[E], E Entity`.

Comment: @MichaelB. I'm not 100% sure I understood the use-case, but it seems to me that `DB[E Entity]` is all the DB's methods need, and if those methods need to pass something as a `proto.Message`, then they can simply do a type assertion. For example say you have `Get(...) (E, error)`, inside that method you can write `v := new(E)` to create a new `*E` instance, then you can do `m, ok := any(v).(proto.Message)` to check if that instance implements the `proto.Message` interface, and if `ok` is `true`, you'd simply pass `m` to `proto.<func_that_needs_message>(m)`.

Comment: @MichaelB. now if implementing `proto.Message` is a requirement for all the structs in the `Entity` union constraint, then using the `Message[E]` is perfectly fine, but if it is optional, then I think using the type-assertion check is the more appropriate approach.

Comment: Yes, I can see how I will most likely end up with assertion in the end as complexity of implementation grows. However, I don't really like the idea of switching from generic to more specific types as it defeats purpose of generic concept in general.
For now, I will stick with `M Message[E], E Entity` type parameter signature, as it creates less clutter and assures (during compile time) newly added Entities can be encoded.